# apache as reverse proxy to tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy, ajp

I have apache configured as reverse proxy to tomcat:

```
ProxyPass /demo/ ajp://demoserver.local:8009/demo/
ProxyPassReverse /demo/ ajp://demoserver.local:8009/demo/
```

Works great. I cant enter http://webserver.local/demo/ and I get to tomcat app's page.

I need to make a change in the url: http://webserver.local/demo123/. So I changed the configuration of the proxy this way:

```
ProxyPass /demo123/ ajp://demoserver.local:8009/demo/
ProxyPassReverse /demo123/ ajp://demoserver.local:8009/demo/
```

I can't get it working though. What happens is that tomcat app sends a redirect to /demo/login.htm and my web browser tries to fetch that url from web server. Web server fires a 404 error since /demo/ is not pointing anywhere.

Could I possibly solve this without touching tomcat's app, just by modifying apache config?

Comment: What happens if you try an internal rewrite?
`RewriteRule ^/demo(.*) /demo123$1` ?

Comment: I get the same result. Even if I navigate to a page that won't redirect me nowhere, css and javascript urls inside that page are pointing to /demo/, not /demo123/, so I guess I can't solve this by just rewriting an url.

Comment: Any reason you can't re-name the web application in Tomcat to also be `/demo123`? That's the easiest solution.

Comment: Yes, that keeps being an option. However we are somewhat dependent on the original name.